# Sequelize Error on DataTypes.ARRAY(DataTypes.STRING)

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I am new to NodeJs development
I am using NodeJs with mysql and Sequelize to create a Batch model with these properties.

```
const Batch = sequelize.define(
  "Batch",
  {
    title: { type: DataTypes.STRING, allowNull: false },
    studentIds: { type: DataTypes.STRING },
    teacherId: { type: DataTypes.STRING, allowNull: true }
  },
  {
    timestamps: false
  }
);
```

On async method call it is working fine.

```
Batch.sync().then((res) => {
  console.log("Batch model sync : ", Batch === sequelize.models.Batch);
});
```

But I need to change

```
studentIds: { type: DataTypes.ARRAY(DataTypes.STRING)}
```

Whenever I make this change it gives error

[image]

I am using node 14.5.0 MySql 8.0.21 and Sequelize 6.3.4

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`DataTypes.ARRAY` is not available on *Mysql*, it's only available on *postgres*.

Check in official docs: [https://sequelize.org/api/v6/class/src/data-types.js~array](https://sequelize.org/api/v6/class/src/data-types.js%7Earray)

Comment: so on mysql , it should be what when I need array

Answer (score 0):

With a small workaround you can use your string data as an array.
Overwrite the getter and setter of the property of the model

```
studentIds: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING,
    get() {
      const stringValue = this.getDataValue('studentIds');
      return stringValue ? rawValue.split(',') : null;
    },
    set(value) {
      const arrayValue = value ? value.join(',') : '';
      this.setDataValue('studentIds', arrayValue);
    },
  },
```